# In Casper JS (based on Phantom JS), how to catch JavaScript errors that are loaded after the DOM is done?

Tags: javascript, dom, phantomjs, casperjs, code-injection

I have a [Casper JS](http://casperjs.org/) script (Casper JS is based on [Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/)), which injects another script into an external URL. The injected script runs code after the DOM is loaded, similar to how jQuery's `$(document).ready()` works.

If the injected script contains a JavaScript error, then Casper JS won't catch it if it's loaded after the DOM. Casper will catch errors if they are run immediately though.

The code below will *not* output the error `ReferenceError: Strict mode forbids implicit creation of global property 'string'`. If you look at the very bottom lines, you can swap the comments on the lines to get this error. I want this error to occur even when running code after the DOM is loaded.

To run the code, install Casper JS and in Console type: `casperjs casper.js`

**casper.js**

```
// Include Casper's "utils" so we can dump variables.
var require = patchRequire(require);
var utils = require('utils');

// Open a URL and inject our JS.
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://example.com/', function() {
  casper.page.injectJs('inject.js');
});

// Wait a moment to give everything time to load, then check that the function
// exists and returns something.
casper.wait(1000, function() {
  var testValue = casper.evaluate(function() {
    return test();
  });

  casper.echo(testValue);
});

// If there are any errors along the way, then print them.
casper.on('page.error', function(msg, trace) {
  casper.echo(msg);
  casper.echo(utils.dump(trace));
});

// Actually run everything.
casper.run();
```

**inject.js**

```
// Be strict on this page so that errors occur.
'use strict';

function run() {
  window.test = function() {
    // An error will occur here because the variable was never declared.
    testing = 'test';
    return testing;
  }
}

// If the below line is used, then "ReferenceError: Strict mode forbids implicit
// creation of global property 'string'" appears as expected.
// run();

// If the below line is used instead of the one above, then the same error does
// not appear.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
```

Comment: casper.on('page.error') is supposed to show any errors on the page, is it not working?

Comment: No, as I said, it won't show the ReferenceError if the run() function is ran via the DOMContentLoaded event listener, rather than ran naked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're injecting script `inject.js` too late, already after the page has loaded and event has fired.

There's a way to inject after the page has initialized but before it's loaded:

```
casper.on('page.initialized', function(msg, trace) {
  casper.echo("Injecting JS");
  casper.page.injectJs('inject.js');
});
```

And another note. You wrote:

> it won't show the ReferenceError if the run() function is ran via the DOMContentLoaded event

As we know now it actually never run via the DOMContentLoaded event. I'm sure you do it but I feel it's very important to stress again that we should log everything, everywhere possible in case of doubt.

So I always add to scripts like `casper.js` not only `page.error`, but also `remote.message` callback to be able to `console.log()` from the casper.page context:

```
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
  casper.echo(msg);
});
```

Then in `inject.js` I add a console.log call:

```
function run() {
  window.test = function() {

    console.log("run() has run");

    // An error will occur here because the variable was never declared.
    testing = 'test';
    return testing;
  }
}
```

and find out that it doesn't run (not that it doesn't just generate error because of strict mode).

Comment: Any reason why the code in DOMContentLoaded does not run at all? I'm using this event for this example because in my actual code, I've imported jQuery via WebPack into the injected code, and that would be too much weight for an example, so I tried to simplify it. I use jQuery's $(document).ready(). The code definitely runs in that case, since tests that I run in Casper can detect changes made by the injected code, which is run after the DOM is done loading.

Comment: Okay so I tested with jQuery's $() and that worked, so of course they did some extra stuff that is more than just a simple DOMContentLoaded. Your tip of using remote.message so I could use console.log to debug was very helpful. I managed to figure things out from there. Ultimately, page.error was indeed the event I needed to use to output the error I wanted.

Comment: I think DOMContentLoaded didn't run because you injected inject.js in page.open callback, when the said event had already fired.